# ZetaSQL Sample Using Apache beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, beam-sql

I am Facing Issues while Using ZetaSQL in Apache beam Framework (2.17.0-SNAPSHOT). After Going through documentation of the apache beam I am not able to find any sample for ZetaSQL.

I tried to add the Planner:
        `options.setPlannerName("org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLQueryPlanner");`

But Still Facing Issue, Snippet is added below for help.

````
    ```
    String sql =
                    "SELECT CAST (1243 as INT64), "
                        + "CAST ('2018-09-15 12:59:59.000000+00' as TIMESTAMP), "
                        + "CAST ('string' as STRING);";

      ZetaSQLQueryPlanner zetaSQLQueryPlanner = new ZetaSQLQueryPlanner();
            BeamRelNode beamRelNode = zetaSQLQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRel(sql);
            PCollection<Row> stream = BeamSqlRelUtils.toPCollection(p, beamRelNode);
    p.run();
````

I Understand we need the below Snippet but failed to create the config 
       Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()

and while Running Code I found below Exceptions:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.zetasql.ClientChannelProvider: Provider com.google.zetasql.JniChannelProvider could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hello! What's your OS? ZetaSQL does not work on Mac and very old version of Linux.

Comment: Hi, @RuiWang Since Apache Beam is Unified Framework its does not matter. I want to use ZetaSQL Planner instead of Calcite in Beam SQL Code. Since Like for Calcite we have an Example similary is there any ref. for ZetaSQL Planner.

Comment: I am commenting for your specific exception because I suspect it is related to your OS. Beam is as unified framework but your exception looks from its dependency: ZetaSQL parser.

Comment: If you change to a newer version of linux I think your code snippet should work.

Comment: @BackBenChers, would you mind to let us know if the suggestion made by Rui Wang worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa Sorry for Delayed Response but yes I tried Rui Solution and it worked.

Comment: Cool! Could you please then @RuiWang post your proposal as an answer? That way it can be registered as a solution!

Comment: Glad it worked. Post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: as of 06/23/2020, Beam ZetaSQL is supported on Mac OS as well (not all versions but at least most recent ones)!

====

I think it is related to your OS. Beam is as unified framework but your exception looks from its dependency: ZetaSQL parser. If you change to a newer version of linux I think your code snippet should work.

Comment: Hi Rui, Is row_number() function available in Beam SQL?